# Convert String in html format to mailto link

Tags: java, html, encoding, mailto

In Java webapp, I need an automatic converter to convert String to use in a mailto link

By example, I have this String "S&D" will be display in a html correctly "S&D". But now I need to have a mailto link in my web page.

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=my%20subject&body=S&amp;D">share</a>
```

its wrong character "&", so I need to convert "&" to "%26".

There is a library to do that?

I tried java.net.URLEncoder but she changed only the "&" not the "&" and she replace space " " by plus "+"
I tried java.net.URI but she did nothing for character "&"!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quoting [RFC 6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068#page-8)(thanks JB Nizet):

> When producing 'mailto' URIs, all spaces SHOULD be encoded as
> %20, and '+' characters MAY be encoded as %2B.  Please note that '+'
> characters are frequently used as part of an email address to
> indicate a subaddress, as for example in `<bill+ietf@example.org>`.

Updated code:

```
String subject = URLEncoder.encode("my subject", "utf-8").replace("+", "%20");
String body = URLEncoder.encode("S&D", "utf-8").replace("+", "%20");
// Email addresses may contain + chars
String email = "test@example.com".replace("+", "%2B");
String link = String.format("mailto:%s?subject=%s&body=%s", email, subject, body);
System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(link));
```

Output:

```
mailto:test@example.com?subject=my%20subject&amp;body=S%26D
```

Which may be used in a link like so:

```
<a href="mailto:test@example.com?subject=my%20subject&amp;body=S%26D">mail me</a>
```

[StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(String str)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml(java.lang.String)) from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).

Comment: This will escape the HTML special chars, but won't encode each parameter in the mailto "request string". Each parameter should first be encoded, then the whole URL should be HTML-escaped.

Comment: The problem is that URLEncoder uses + for spaces, and this doesn't work with mailto links (the + is literally in the subject of the mail). But parameters must be encoded some way, at least for a multiline body. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6068#page-8

Comment: URLEncoder.encode("S&D", "UTF-8") works yes, but URLEncoder.encode("S&amp;D", "UTF-8") doesn't work! I retrieve html character and I need to convert to mailtolink.

Comment: The link in source page is S%26amp%3BD and the result in the mail client software is S&amp;D

Comment: For me, `S&D` gets correctly encoded as `S%26D`. I have added output and usage in my answer.